# What's the difference between the keyboard shortcut commands and bash ones?

Tags: command-line, bash, shortcut-keys, date

When I type in a terminal :

```
gnome-screenshot -a -f /home/manuel/Desktop/"`date`".png
```

I have the intended result, a file named `"dimanche 10 avril 2016, 23:36:50 (UTC+0200).png"` is created.

However, when I try to link this with a keyboard shortcut, I get instead the a file named

```
"`date`.png"
```

When I try further

```
bash -c "gnome-screenshot -a -f /home/manuel/Desktop/"`date`".png"
```

the file becomes `dimanche` meaning it stops at the 1st whitespace.

I read that while quoting a bash variable, to include whitespaces one must use quotes, which seems I did. So I later tried assigning the `date` command to a `$times` variable and using `"$times"` in the command  but with the same result.

So my question is why must bash always be a pain in the ass? If it is indeed the culprit.

Thank you, if no one answers I hope creating a bash file instead will solve this as a last resort as it has many times before...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shortcuts in System Settings -> "Keyboard" -> "Shortcuts" -> "Custom Shortcuts" are not run in a shell.

That's why `` gnome-screenshot -a -f /home/manuel/Desktop/"`date`".png `` creates a file named `` "`date`.png" ``; the `` /home/manuel/Desktop/"`date`".png `` part is not interpreted and is passed verbatim to `gnome-screenshot`, which creates a file named `` "`date`.png" ``.

`` bash -c "gnome-screenshot -a -f /home/manuel/Desktop/"`date`".png" `` instead doesn't work simply because you're not escaping the second level of quotes, which makes Bash run `date` in an uquoted subshell which is subject to word splitting.

So just escape the second level of quotes:

```bsh
bash -c "gnome-screenshot -a -f /home/manuel/Desktop/\"`date`\".png"
```

Or even better use single quotes in the outer command so to not have to escape a second level of quotes:

```bsh
bash -c 'gnome-screenshot -a -f /home/manuel/Desktop/"`date`".png'
```

On a side note using ``` `` ``` is deprecated and discouraged; it would be better to use `$()`:

```bsh
bash -c 'gnome-screenshot -a -f /home/manuel/Desktop/"$(date)".png'
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a executeable script:

Edit a file i.e. /usr/bin/myscreenshot with a editor of your choice as root, i.e.

```
sudo vi /usr/bin/myscreenshot
```

Paste this content in the file

```
#!/bin/bah
gnome-screenshot -a -f "/home/$USER/Desktop/`date`.png"
```

Make the file to be a executeable script:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/myscreenshot
```

Finaly create a keyboard shortcut to this program and it should be done.

Comment: I had already included the possibility in my question so I'll wait for a more complete answer. If I find none, you'll have my vote though.